# MySQL Regex If string contains hyphen after 5 digits

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string

So I have a `slug` column in my table and due to some bad coding, some of my slugs are messed up and need to be fixed.

I need to find all slugs that have a hyphen on *both* sides of exactly 5 digits, somewhere in the middle of the string.

So here's three samples of slugs:

```
321-sw-2nd-ave-portland-or-97204-2-3-4-5
321-sw-2nd-ave-portland-or-97204-2-3
430-e-25th-st-tacoma-wa-98421
```

My expression would match the first and second but not the third one.

I would like to then get rid of those extra things after the zip code.

Here's what I have tried so far, but my Regex skills are lacking big time.

`^(.)*d{5}-(.)*$`

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  Regexes changed with 8.0.

Comment: Do you need to _extract_ the slug?  Or just identify rows that have a 'slug+hyphen'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to match on the entire string. I would simply do a partial match on the part that you are interested in. Another problem with your regex is that you use `d` to represent a digit: MySQL wants `\\d`; also, this notation is only supported from 8.0 (in earlier versions, you need `[0-9]`).

Consider:

```
slug RLIKE '[0-9]{5}-'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1d25f452530ce2b012b6145157e4652c)**:

```
with t as (
    select '321-sw-2nd-ave-portland-or-97204-2-3-4-5' slug
    union all select '321-sw-2nd-ave-portland-or-97204-2-3'
    union all select '430-e-25th-st-tacoma-wa-98421'
)
select slug from t where slug RLIKE '[0-9]{5}-'
```

```
| slug                                     |
| :--------------------------------------- |
| 321-sw-2nd-ave-portland-or-97204-2-3-4-5 |
| 321-sw-2nd-ave-portland-or-97204-2-3     |
```

Comment: That doesn't work because sometimes the address can start with 5 digits too. Sorry I should have mentioned that.  So that expression would match this one as well: `15645-eastlake-parade-kingston-act-2604`.  However maybe `slug RLIKE '-[0-9]{5}-'` would work.

Comment: @zen: yes, `-[0-9]{5}-` should work for this: see [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=db4b6506be98f10691d05bd84d1a8f4c)